# Cann't set the state data from response data

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing in the axios to get data from webAPI . The problem is state is empty

```
componentDidMount() {
        uploadFilesService.getFiles().then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                fileInfos: response.data,
            });
            console.log('check 1', response.data)
            console.log('check 2', this.state.fileInfos)

        });
    }
```

[image]

The other project with the same method is OK .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the use second argument of setState

```
this.setState({
  fileInfos: response.data,
}, () => {
 // do something with the new state
});
```

From React doc:

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function
> that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is
> re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for
> such logic instead.